# Find the semidirect products of $C_2\times C_2$ by $C_3$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

**Find the semidirect products of $C_2 \times C_2$ by $C_3$, that is: $(C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_3$**

My approach: I let $C_3:=\langle y\rangle$ and let $\phi : C_3 \to \mathrm{Aut}(C_2 \times C_2)$ be a homomorphism, observe that $\mathrm{Aut}(C_2 \times C_2) \cong \mathrm{GL}(2,2)$ and $\phi(y)$ has order 1 or 3.

Case 1: If $\phi(y)$ has order 1, then $\phi$ is the trivial homomorphism thus $(C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_3 \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 $

Case2: If $\phi(y)$ has order 3, then $\phi(y)= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $ which is the only matrix of order 3 inside $\mathrm{GL}(2,2)$, in the next step one needs to find the isomorphism type of $(C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_3$ 
relised by $\phi$ in this case, this is where my problem is: I know its presentation $\langle a,b,y\rangle$ contains  $ \{ a^2=1,\ b^2=1,\ [a,b]=1,\ y^3=1 \} $ as a part of the relations, but I do not know how to get all the relations, and also how to get its isomorphism type.

Comment: I guess the cheap way to show that this is $A_4$ is to note that it's the only non-abelian [group of order $12$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups) with a unique subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: Note that you used different notation for cyclic groups in the title and in the body. Moreover, in the title you had $Z_2*Z_2$; that's the **free** product, not the direct product.

Comment: Isn't the idea that conjugation by $x$ gives the automorphism $\phi(y)$? Also, instead of matrices you can think of $\phi(y)$ as simply permuting the three non-trivial elements $a,b,ab$ of $C_2\times C_2$ in a 3-cycle. So $xax^{-1}=b$, $xbx^{-1}=ab$, $\ldots$ Some redundancy may already be here,

Comment: Also, if there's one matrix of order $3$ inside $GL_2(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)$ then there are two. [Look at the inverse of the one you have.] This doesn't give you a new semidirect product, though.

Comment: Your presentation needs to say how $x$ interacts with $a$ and $b$; otherwise, what you have is $(C_2\times C_2)*C_3$, the free product of $C_2\times C_2$ with $C_3$. The missing relations are $a^x = b$ and $b^x = ab$.

Comment: Actually, you should just read this: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I was confused about how to get the extra two interations of y,a and b, now it's more clear.